# Is there is an existing parser for `.gitignore` files?

Tags: regular-expressions, git, find-file

Is there is an existing parser for `.gitignore` files? Maybe there is some Elisp package that includes something like this?

Ideally, I would like to be able to read a `.gitignore` file in a given directory and all parent directories up to the project root and convert the file to list of regular expressions.

This list could be used to filter the results of various commands. In particular, I would like to use it in `helm-find-files`.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this, or roll your own?